# WINGET - out of control in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, resource-usage, winget

As other users have already experienced, the winget process is consuming way more processor capacity than anything else here, causing my fans to spin up and the hard disks to chatter loudly. I never aksed for winget to be installed and it has arrived with an update and regularly takes over the PC. Restarts and updates haven't helped, and the process can't be killed like others, which is quite suspicious. It seems that I am being told again how my computer must be configured and what programs/apps I should have, rather than me choosing for myself. How do I get control back?

Comment: Is your `winget` located inside folder `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`? How come it's running without you launching it?

Comment: No, only Edge is in there, (which I have successfully managed to disable). It is in  C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages Something must be starting this nuisance process - it's not me!

Comment: That's a legal location, so your `winget` seems correct. Try in *Settings > Apps* to scroll to "Windows Package Manager Source (winget)", click on it and select Uninstall.

Comment: Thanks Harry, that worked - it has been deinstalled. The processor and disk usage are normal again. I'm curious to see now how long it takes before it is automatically REinstalled !

Comment: I added it as answer. Keep me posted on future changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `winget` seems correct and is not a virus.

Try to uninstall it :

- Run *Settings > Apps*
- Scroll to "Windows Package Manager Source (winget)"
- Click on it and select "Uninstall".